# how to import sample database sakila, mysql

Tags: mysql

I've downloaded a sample database called sakila-db from the mysql website.

How do I import this database from my desktop into mysql via the command line in my terminal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check the [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-installation.html); steps are outlined very well. Listing them from document

- Extract the installation archive to a temporary location
- Connect to the MySQL server using the `mysql` command-line client
- Execute the `sakila-schema.sql` script
- Execute the `sakila-data.sql` script
- Confirm that the sample database is installed correctly